# Como fazer o TextInput imprimir o numero 1 toda vez que pressionar o Buttom?

Tags: react, react-native, react-hooks

Como fazer o `TextInput` imprimir o numero **1** toda vez que pressionar o `button`?

Exemplo: se eu pressionar 5 vezes o `button`, quero que apareça "11111" no `TextInput`.

```
const App = () => {

  const state={
    newNumber: 1,
    number: ''
  };

  const printNumber = () => {
     const resultado = this.state.newNumber;

     this.setState({
       number: resultado
     });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
         value={this.number}
        onChangeText={(text) =>this.setState({number})}
      />
      
      <Button title="1" onPress={printNumber} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um problema no seu código cade o [react-hooks](/questions/tagged/react-hooks) no seu código, não pode iniciar o estado igual era com componente (*vide meu exemplo*).

Basicamente, o código é concatenar os valores existente com uma texto que representa o número `"1"`, que na linguagem precisa que o valor a ser concatenado seja um texto, exemplo mínimo:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [n, setN] = React.useState(''); 
  const handleChange = (e) => setN(state => state + "1");
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={n} onChange={e => setN(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleChange}>adicionar</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

<sup>***Observação:*** o snippet aqui é [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), mas, o conceito é o mesmo para [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native)</sup>

---

No seu código é basicamente:

```
const App = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(''); 
    
    const printNumber = () => {
        setNumber(state => state + "1");
    }
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>   
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                value={this.number}
                onChangeText={(text) => setNumber(state => state + text)}
            />    
            <Button title="1" onPress={printNumber} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

dessa forma vai funcionar a digitação e também quando pressionar o botão.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Entendi a ideia. Colei o código e removi o "this" que estava no 'value' do 'TextInput'. Funcionou perfeito.

Comment: Se for util a resposta @MarcosCruz assinale como resposta para ajudar a comunidade

Comment: Não sei como fazer.

Comment: @MarcosCruz leia por favor: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta simplesmente é isso assinale a resposta e positive se assim for de sua vontade (seta para cima você deu uma resposta útil e o check abaixo da setas é aceitando como resposta da sua pergunta) leia as respostas